# Why my code doesn't work when executed from the task scheduler?

Tags: python, excel

I have created a code that usually run without any problem when executed through command prompt. Through this code, I want to generate a png file from the excel table that will be updated automatically in a daily basis. So firstly I run the 1st code that will update my excel table using task scheduler (not using command prompt manually), and then after that I set the my 2nd code like below to generate the png file.

But the 2nd code run smoothly only if i run it manually through the command prompt, the excel file will pop up, creating like a 'shadow' image, and then excel file closes by itself.. but If i set it to run automatically through the task scheduler, the program will only open and creating that 'shadow' picture but doesn't close the excel file and somehow failed to produce the png file.

Anybody could advise me what to do here? I really appreciate your help

Add: btw, if i open the task scheduler, goes to cmd, and execute the program, it will not work as well.. so the task scheduler tab should be closed and it will run without problem

```
import win32com.client
import xlwings as xw
from PIL import ImageGrab
import os
from datetime import datetime
import time

x = datetime.now()
print(x.strftime("%d%b%y"))
day = x.strftime("%d")
month = x.strftime("%b")
year = x.strftime("%y")

excelfilename = 'Argus ICI 4 Forward Prices SGX.xlsx'
path = r'C:\Users\asus\Desktop\KCH\Automation\SGX\%s' %excelfilename


imagename = 'SGX Data Image %s' %(x.strftime("%d%b%y")) + '.png'
pathimage= r'C:\Users\asus\Desktop\KCH\Automation\SGX\%s' %imagename
print("Image saved under: ", imagename)

app=xw.App(visible=True, add_book=False)
wb=app.books.open(path)
sheet=wb.sheets[0]
all=sheet.used_range
#print(all.value)
all.api.CopyPicture()
time.sleep(1)
sheet.api.Paste()
pic=sheet.pictures[0]
pic.api.Copy()
img = ImageGrab.grabclipboard()
img.save(pathimage)

wb.close()
app.quit()
```

Comment: check environment including working directory.

Comment: do you mind to explain me more about that @Abel? I am new to python and my skill and knowledge is limited to coding with google help such as 'how to....'

Comment: works in cmd and not task scheduler means something is different. first in the cmd where it would have worked run `set > cmdenv.txt` and `cd >> cmdenv.txt` look at the created file content.  then instead of running your script, run one that does the same from python (you can `import os` and either look at `os.environ` or even run a .bat with `os.system`)